# Copy a different config file for each Android Studio Gradle build type

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm just about to switch from ant to gradle as my Android build system. One problem that I could not figure out how to fix is the use of different config files per build type.

In the project root, there is a folder `config` which contains a file for the debug and one for the release build. When building the project, the appropriate file should be copied to the resources folder.

Simplified build.gradle:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            // copy config/config_debug.xml to res/values/config.xml
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            ...
            // copy config/config_release.xml to res/values/config.xml
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I have tried different things like

```
def configFile = 'XXX'
task copyConfigFileTask(type: Copy) {
    println "-> using config file $configFile"
    from 'config/$configFile'
    into 'res/values'
    rename {
        fileName -> 'config.xml'
    }
    outputs.upToDateWhen {
        false
    }
}

assembleDebug.dependsOn {
    copyConfigFileTask { configFile = 'config_release.xml' }
    copyConfigFileTask.execute()
}
```

but that doesn't really work. I cannot imagine that such a simple and common task is so complicated with Gradle, is it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Put the debug version in `src/debug/res/values/config.xml`.

Step #2: Put the release version in `src/release/res/values/config.xml`.

Step #3: Beer.

Debug builds will pull in the `debug` version of your file. Release builds will pull in the `release` version of your file. No muss, no fuss.

Comment: Or alternately, the debug version in `src/main/res/values/config.xml` as the default for all non-release versions.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Yeah, I'd probably set it up that way too, but I wanted to more closely mirror the OP's original setup.

Comment: I have imported the project from eclipse, so i still have that old structure. I define the resources dir in the `build.gradle` with `sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['res'] ...`. I have tried to just add the release config in `res/release/values/config.xml`, but that does not seem to work. Is there a way to do that without changing the whole project structure?

Comment: @SimonSays: In `sourcesets {}` you can have statements like `debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')` and `release.setRoot('build-types/release')` to indicate where the sourcesets for those build types reside. I have never actually tried putting files there, but in principle, given the above code, `build-types/debug/res/values/config.xml` and `build-types/release/res/values/config.xml` would work.

Comment: @SimonSays: Upon further reflection, you'd probably be better served going with ianhanniballake's suggestion: put the debug version of `config.xml` in its normal spot (`res/values/config.xml`), with the release one in the `build-types/` location. Since Eclipse doesn't know about these build type sourcesets, it needs one version of `config.xml` for its own use, and the debug one would be the safest answer.

Comment: I solved it by leaving the debug version on it's usual place in the normal `res/values` folder. For the release version, I created a new folder `project_root/release/res/values` and defined it in `sourceSet { release.res.srcDirs = ['release/res'] ...`. This overrides the debug version with the release one on build time. Thanks a lot for the input!!